# Keeping a track of internal nodes in a binary tree in a postorder fashion

Tags: recursion

I have recently started learning recursion and I found it quite interesting, which made me dig even deeper into it. That's why I started learning about trees and about how to recurse through them. Upon working with them, I came up with an interesting task - I wanted to keep a track of all the internal nodes in a binary tree and number them accordingly.

For instance, if my tree was as follows:

```
       7
     /    \
    /      \
   3        11
  /  \     /  \
 /     \  /    \
2      5 9     13
```

I would want my code to figure out that the internal node with value 3 is at position 0, the internal node with the value of 11 is at position 2 and the internal node with value 7 is at position 3 by modifying their attributes, as was done below.

That's what I have tried doing:

```
def number_internal_nodes(self):
    """
     Return a list with tuples containing the number of internal nodes
     inside the tree along with their indices starting from 0, in
      post-order.

      >>> bst = BinarySearchTree(7)
      >>> left = BinarySearchTree(3)
      >>> left._left = BinarySearchTree(2)
      >>> left._right = BinarySearchTree(5)
      >>> right = BinarySearchTree(11)
      >>> right._left = BinarySearchTree(9)
      >>> right._right = BinarySearchTree(13)
      >>> bst._left = left
      >>> bst._right = right
      >>> bst.number_internal_nodes()
      3
      >>> bst._left.pos
      0
      >>> bst._right.pos
      1
      >>> bst.pos
      2
      """

      if self._root is None:
          return 0
      elif self._left._root is None and self._right._root is None:
          return 0
      else:
          i = 1

          i += self._left.number_internal_nodes()
          i += self._right.number_internal_nodes()
          self.pos = i - 1
          return i
```

My code almost works except the following test case fails: bst._right.pos (Expected: 1. Got: 0).

I'm not really sure what I might be doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the idea of an "internal node" is unclear. It looks like you're choosing to define it as a node with at least one child from this part:

```
elif self._left._root is None and self._right._root is None:
  return 0
```

So, we're looking for nodes with at least one child, and we're trying to find their "position". This is another unclear idea. It sounds like what you're after is a post-order count (i.e., bottom-up and left-to-right).

What you've implemented is a height metric, not a post-order count. I'll try to demonstrate the difference with a larger example tree:

```
          20
      /         \
     10         30
   /   \       /   \
  5    15     25    35
 / \   / \    / \   / \
2   7 12 17  22 27 32 37
```

In this example, `5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 and 35` are all "internal" nodes. What you want, I think, is to find them in the following order: `5, 15, 10, 25, 35, 30, 20` (bottom-up, left-to-right). This is called a post-order traversal.

What your code does, though, is assigns each node a number based on the number of nodes beneath it. That's more like a height (it's not quite a height either, but it's not a traversal either).

These nodes will all have position `0`: `5, 15, 25, 35`, because they have no "internal" children, so this code will always set the position to `0` and return `1`:

```
i = 1
i += self._left.number_internal_nodes() # Returns 0
i += self._right.number_internal_nodes() # Returns 0
self.pos = i - 1 # 1-1 = 0, position is always 0
return i # Returns 1
```

That's why in your example you're getting `0` for the right node.

What you want instead is to keep track of a global position variable while traversing the tree in post-order.

```
def assign_postorder_positions_to_internal_nodes(self, position):
  if self._root is None:
    # Don't modify the position
    return position
  elif self._left._root is None and self._right._root is None:
    # Don't modify the position
    return position
  else:
    position = self._left.assign_postorder_positions_to_internal_nodes(position)
    position = self._right.assign_postorder_positions_to_internal_nodes(position)
    self.pos = position
    position += 1
    return position
```

Importantly, note that we go down the left and right directions before assigning the position of the current node. The position is initially 0, and gets incremented only on "internal" nodes.

Hope this helps!

Helpful link: [tree traversals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/).